# EJB/Servlet Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee, ejb

I'm new for what about j2EE and I'm moving my first steps with servlet and EJB.  I use Netbeans, Glassfish. When I pass my data (I want to view in my JSP the data in the table Products on postgress and the connection I sure that works)  from servlet to JSP I have a strange Null Pointer Exception. 
This is the processRequestMethod in the Servlet class:

```
        protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

         List<Products> list=new ArrayList<Products>();
        list =  productsFacade.findAll(); 

        request.setAttribute("list", list);

        String arg = "/" + this.getServletName() + ".jsp";
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(arg);
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
}
```

the method findAll():

```
public List<Products> findAll()
    {
      return em.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Products p").getResultList();
    }
```

Instead the JSP is this:

```
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@page import="entities.Products"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html"%>
<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page import="entities.Products_"%>
 <%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%
    List<Products> list=new ArrayList<Products>();
    list = (List<Products>)request.getAttribute("list");
 %>
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
 <html>
     <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
         <title>JSP Page</title>
      </head>
     <body>
     <h1>Content of my Table</h1>
     <% 

         if (list != null) 
          { for (Products e: list)
              { out.println(e.getName() + " " + e.getPrice() + "<br/>"); }
          }           
       %>    
      </body>
  </html>
```

Why my list is NULL ?

Comment: Because `setAttribute("list", list)` and `getAttribute("lista")` is not using the same name.

Comment: Also, you should use JSTL and the `<c:forEach>` loop it provides.

Comment: getAttribute("lista") is my error on stackoverflow, but on code is right. The problem persists.

Comment: So what URL are you using to access the page?

Comment: The URL is correct. In fact the  jsp page  shows on browser the text <h1>Content of my table</h1>

Comment: So what URL are you using to access the page? What is the value of the `<servlet-name>` and `<url-pattern>` elements of the `<servlet-mapping>` in your `web.xml` file, or corresponding `name` and `urlPatterns` attributes of the `@WebServlet` annotation?